# array elements into unique div tag

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to make a unique `div` for each element in the array `$divs`:

```
$divs= array("div1", "div2", "div3", "div4");
foreach($divs as $div) {

}

$output='<div> random words </div'; 
}
```

So basicly I would like to get something like markup below and also if I add more into the array, would like more unique div tags to be generated:

```
<div> div 1</div>
<div> div 2</div>
<div> div 3</div>
<div> div 4</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: There are some suspicious closing curly brace at the end of your sample. Is it a typo or probably bad copypaste?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your result:

```
$divs= array("div1", "div2", "div3", "div4");

foreach($divs as $div) {
    echo "<div>".$div."</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to add below line in your foreach loop

```
 echo "<div>".$div."</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$divs= array("div1", "div2", "div3", "div4");

$output = '';

foreach($divs as $div) {
     $output .="<div id='$div'> random words </div>"; 
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (more elegant for me):

```
echo sprintf('<div>%s</div>', implode('</div><div>', $divs));
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Comment: It is not - in this case.
the "echo" is for demo-purposes - for the code about, sprintf is the only one, which is useable, because there is no direct output to STDOUT here.

Comment: Um, what? There is nothing preventing the use of the more direct and concise `printf()`.

Comment: he want's to concenate all the output to an $output-variable -- there is no chance to use printf() in this case.
My sprintf with the "echo" is just for demo purposes, he can drop-in replace it to:

"$output .= sprintf(...);"

Comment: If you want to demo saving the data to a variable, use `sprintf()`.  If you want to demo printing, use `printf()`. Demoing `echo sprintf()` is only going to teach people to do a silly thing.